# Openshift - Get user IP address on websocket connection

Tags: openshift, wildfly

I'd like to log the user's IP address in an OpenShift application. I'm using this access log pattern in my WildFly application server configuration:

```
<access-log pattern="%{i,X-Forwarded-For} | %A%t%h%l%u%r%s%b%T%I" directory="${jboss.home.dir}" prefix="access" suffix=".log"  worker="default"/>
```

So it basically logs the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

It works just fine for HTTP connections, but it prints a single `-` character instead of the client's real IP address when a websocket connection is made.

I've found this bug ticket: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1313395, but there seems to be a commit that fixes the problem.

Is there a way to get the user's real IP address in this situation?

Comment: Obviously, this problem is not fixed at all.

Comment: **Update** : they have fixed this issue, `X-Forwarded-For` is now properly filled with the user IP address, even for websocket connections.